# Dynamically accessing empty list or appending to existing one

Tags: r, list

I am having problem accessing a list which is dynamically being formed.

I am trying to form a list of values, such that the first element of the list is the first element of `x`, and at each iteration, if the length of the list is already 3 or if it already contains any element of x, form a new element of the list. This is to be done 5 times in total.
However, the first line of the `for` loop below doesn't work, although I tried different combinations of `[[]]` and `[]` (the part in ** below) - it keeps telling me I cannot access the elements of the list.

My code is as follows:

```
x = c(1,2)
GROUP <- list()
j=1
k=1
for (i in 1:5) {
  **GROUP[[k]][[j]] = i**
  if (length(GROUP[[k]]) == 3 | (any(x %in% GROUP[[k]]))) {
    k = k + 1
  } else {
    j = j + 1
  }
}
```

The expected output is

```
GROUP[[1]] = 1
GROUP[[2]] = 2
GROUP[[3]] = c(3,4,5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most optimal solution, but works.  I added additional condition to check if `[[k]]` exists. If it already exists `i` gets appended.

```
x <- 1:2
GROUP <- list()
j <- 1
k <- 1

for (i in 1:5) {
    # Check the length of current list
    if (length(GROUP) < k) {
        # Creates are new vector
        GROUP[[length(GROUP) + 1]] <- i
    } else {
        # Appends to existing vector
        GROUP[[k]] <- append(GROUP[[k]], i)
    }
    if (length(GROUP[[k]]) == 3 | any(x %in% GROUP[[k]])) {
        k <- k + 1
    } else {
        j <- j + 1
    }
}
```